# How do I store a Random number generator in a struct?

Tags: random, rust

I am trying to store a Random number generator in a struct. I can't seem to get the struct definition for any Rng structs to be recognized, like ThreadRng. This works:

```
use rand::{
    self,
    distributions::{Distribution, Uniform},
}; // 0.6.4

fn main() {
    let mut rng  = rand::thread_rng();
    let die_range = Uniform::new_inclusive(1, 6);
    let die = die_range.sample(&mut rng);
    println!("{}", die);
}
```

However, if I try to define a variable to have the actual type of the Rng, I get an error:

```
use rand::{
    self,
    ThreadRng,
    distributions::{Distribution, Uniform},
}; // 0.6.4

fn main() {
    let mut rng :ThreadRng = rand::thread_rng();
    let die_range = Uniform::new_inclusive(1, 6);
    let die = die_range.sample(&mut rng);
    println!("{}", die);
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rand::ThreadRng`
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     ThreadRng,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^
  |     |
  |     no `ThreadRng` in the root
  |     help: a similar name exists in the module: `thread_rng`
```

I want to store the Rng in a struct, and I do not want a trait object. How do I import the definition of ThreadRng? Or XorShiftRng (which might be faster - I do not need cryptographic strength)? Is the type in some sub-module I don't know about? All the examples I read online call a method to get the Rng and use it locally; they never store it in a struct and never define any variables that use the struct name.

Comment: According to the documentation, the type is actually [`rand::rngs::ThreadRng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html). Have you tried that?

Comment: No. I missed that little note. Reading the source code gave me no clue.

Comment: It works! Post that as an answer and I will accept. Spent an hour trying all sorts of things... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation [`rand::thread_rng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/fn.thread_rng.html), you can click on its return type to see that its fully qualified name is actually [`rand::rngs::ThreadRng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html).